# Apply external theme apk to system wide apps programatically

Tags: android, apk, android-theme, android-install-apk

So basically i have a theme.apk file i wanted to know how do i set this theme to the system i.e default icons ,default wallpaper,default font all should be changed system wide. I searched through many answers but all i found is about themeing my app/activity .I did not find any answers related to system wide changes. for e.g if i install this apk through my app it should change default font to the fonts included in my theme .apk system wide.

following thing is what i tried to do

```
String packagename="com.....";
Resources res = 
context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packagename);
int strid = res.getIdentifier(packagename+":string/"+name, "string",packagename);
int drawableid = res.getIdentifier(packagename+":drawable/"+name, "drawable", packagename);

String name = res.getString(resid);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resid);
```

but i have reached dead end. about how to proceed

Comment: Using public APIs your can't. There might be some hidden API or xposed module, or some manufacturer specific API. But Android currently does not support programmatically changing system wide theme.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when accessing system resources in android you have classes that have the prefix `Manager`. So for example you could use a `WallpaperManager` to set the background of your phone.

Example: http://android-er.blogspot.co.at/2011/03/set-wallpaper-using-wallpapermanager.html

However I have not been able to find a Manager class for fonts :/

Comment: Well [ this article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/10573/android-how-to-change-the-default-system-font-requires-root-or-adb/) states, that you need to root your device in order to change the system default font (and add a new font to the system).

This makes sense, because you have to access the systems files to add a new font template .ttf

Comment: rooting wont work for me..i think i might have to design my own launcher for it.

Comment: No problem :) I am always amazed how many experts are on this forum. Unfortunately I am not one of them so do not assume, that my answer is completely true.